# Choose where the cursor is when starting application in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have a form with a password field, a text field and a button. It's a login form. I set the prompt text to username and password. The problem is that when I launch my form, the cursor starts in the text field and the user can't see the prompt text unless they click somewhere else. Can I start the app without having the text field selected?

Comment: No need to show code.... And the question got answered already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `requestFocus()` on whatever node you want to have the initial focus.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still learning javafx and your answer really helped me.